# What are these carrier configuration settings and which Android service handles them?

Tags: updates, settings, sms, mobile-network, services

I signed a new mobile contract and received a carrier configuration message, but it seems that the settings were not updated properly. Up- and download is way too slow (typical 3G speeds) despite "4G" being displayed in the status bar. Which **Android service** is responsible for automatically updating carrier configuration settings and which settings are relevant for 4G connectivity?

Device, OS: Samsung Galaxy A40 (SM-A405FN) with Android 9.0

Carrier: Telefónica

Data plan: 3 GB LTE

These are the [APN settings](https://www.mobilcom-debitel.de/downloads/service/vertrag/sonstige/manuelle_Konfiguration.pdf) (3rd column) as **specified by the carrier**:

> Mobile Data:
>
> - *APN*
> - *Username*
> - *Password*
> - *MCC*
> - *MNC*
> - *Authentication Type*
>
> MMS:
>
> - *APN*
> - *Username*
> - *Password*
> - *MMSC*
> - *MMS-Proxy*
> - *MMS-Port*
> - *MCC*
> - *MNC*
> - *Authentication Type*
> - *Max. Message Size*

The following settings are **not specified by the carrier** (device preset values in brackets) or even non-existent in the device menu (x):

> Mobile Data:
>
> - *Proxy*
> - *Port*
>
> MMS:
>
> - *APN Type* ("default, supl, mms, xcap, email")
> - *APN Protocol* ("IPv4")
> - *APN Roaming Protocol* ("IPv4")
> - *Bearer* ("none")
> - *Mobile Virtual Network Operator Type* ("none")
> - *Max. Message Size* (x)
>
> ...not sure where this belongs:
>
> - *Server*

What are the correct settings? What about the following:

> - *Authentication Type*: "empty" (carrier) - vs. - "PAP" or "**CHAP**" (isn't the latter more secure?)
> - *Bearer*: "unspecified" (carrier) - vs. - e.g. "**LTE**" (doesn't this affect speed?)
> - *APN Protocol*, *APN Roaming Protocol*: ...shouldn't this be set to "**IPv6**"?
> - *Mobile Virtual Network Operator Type*: "none/SPN/IMSI/GID" ...what is this?

Comment: Those configuration messages usually just set the APN and may be some proxy settings (depends on the carrier). Carries often have a manual what APN values to set by hand. Search on your carriers home-page for it.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good start. I've updated the question!

Comment: If you have applied the settings and nothing has changed then I doubt that this is a configuration issue. May be the speed is limited for your contract (very typical for a mobile contract in Germany) or your device is too old or not perfectly compatible with the frequencies used by your carrier. In any way as you neither tell use your exact device model nor the exact carrier and data plan I don't see how we could help you further.

Comment: Your settings are carrier specific, any settings not specified by the carrier should be blank or default... That said, this is NOT an Android specific related question in any way, but is generic. Voting to close.

Comment: Device model, carrier, and data plan have been added to the question. What about the Authentication Type: I tried empty/PAP/CHAP and all settings seem to work (full connection). Also, is it technically possible that any of the last three settings (Bearer, APN Protocol/APN Roaming Protocol, Mobile Virtual Network Operator Type) have any influence on the bandwidth? Btw, this IS an Android-related question (please read carefully).